# How to save current row in a list?

Tags: vb.net

I'm iterating through a `DataTable` that contains the results of database records. Now, I have declared a list of DataRow:

```
Dim Records as List(Of DataRow)

'Loop

For i As Integer = 0 To Dt.Rows.Count - 1

    Records.Add(Dt.Rows(i)) 'Here the error

Next
```

On the `Records.Add` line I get:

> reference not set to an instance of an object

but why? What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the list with [`New`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx):

```
Dim Records as New List(Of DataRow)
```

But why do you want to store these rows in a `List(Of DataRow)` at all? You have already a collection that's sole purpose is to store `DataRows`: the `DataTable`.

Comment: Is hard to explain, essentially I'm developing a system that allow me to understand which records must be updated. The original code is more different against this, anyway you're right, I missing to init the list. Thanks :D

Comment: @Sandokan: normally the best way is to use pure sql. So write a query that detects which rows must be updated. For example: `UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table Table_A
INNER JOIN
    Other_Table Table_B
ON
    Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'some value'`

Comment: I know this, but I've different database, one local and another online. So as I said, the situation is a 'bit more difficult. Anyway, how I can iterate on the DataRow? I tried with:  Console.WriteLine(Records.Item(i).Table.Rows(i)) but I get this: System.Data.DataRow, I need to get a list of parameter to insert later in MySqlCommand and send to the propertly table.

Comment: @Sandokan: `Records.Item(i)` is already the `DataRow` so no reason to use `....Table.Rows(i)`. But what do you mean with _"iterate on DataRow"_ at all? You can get a field of a row either via name or index. Presuming that a column `Name` exists: `Dim name=Records(i).Field(Of String)("Name")`

Comment: I mean, this DataRow simply contain the records to update, but this records have different field 'cause belonging of different tables. Now as you know each MySqlCommand have a list of parameters. There is a way to set automatically this parameters simply passing Table.Rows(i)? Because is hard coding save all parameter in a variables and create MySqlCommand. For exaple MyCommand.Clone, that allow me to clone also the parameter of another MySqlCommand.

Comment: @Sandokan: you should ask another question since it's difficult to answer this in comments